# Why isn't my bulk variable assignment working as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make it small (short), but it is not happening, please tell me where I am wrong. And where I am wrong, you correct there...

```
var set1 = document.querySelector(".get1");
var set2 = document.querySelector(".get2");
var set3 = document.querySelector(".get3");
var set4 = document.querySelector(".get4");
```

to..

```
var ("[set1],[set2],[set3],[set4]") 
  = document.querySelector("[.get1],[.get2],[.get3],[.get4]")
```

but it's not work

First code is work very well but the second code which is a shortened form of the first code is not working

Comment: Don't overcomplicate things. The first code example is fine. Short code can be beautiful, but readable code is always better. The only thing I would say, is that you could potentially put the same class on all the elements, `.get`, then use `querySelectorAll()`. This will give you a single Collection you can work with. As with anything, the best way to do something depends on the exact problem you're trying to solve. As you've not told us that, we can't really offer any effective help.

Comment: The shortened form is not valid JS at all. You cannot assign to *strings*.  You're looking for a destructuring assignment. However, that cannot be used here *unless* there a guarantee that there is a single item with each class in the DOM.

Comment: Assuming you'll have 100s of these to save a bunch of coding (rather than just 4) and you *really* can't find another way to do this...  then as a one liner: `for (var i=1;i<=4;++i) { window["set"+i] = document.querySelector(".get" + i); }`  if you don't know how many (and they start at 1 and are in sequence) `var count = $("[class*='get']").length;`  https://jsfiddle.net/j8Lr7p42/

Comment: @freedomn-m if there is really a variable amount of values needed, then the correct thing is to use an array. Or maybe an object with dynamic keys.

Comment: @VLAZ indeed.  And if there were variable number, what would be the point in defining them in code?  You can't reference `set99.value` if you don't know there's 99.   And if there's 100s of them then there *must* be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [destrcutring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to transform your given array and then assign it to individual values. You can do this:

```
let [var1,var2,var3,var4] = 
    ['.get1','.get2','.get3','.get4'].map(x => document.querySelector(x));
```

**But as mentioned your code is fine the way it is. It is simpler and easier to understand.**

Comment: While this works (except in IE) one thing to note, especially for the OP who seems hell-bent on making the code as short as possible, is that you're sacrificing both performance and readability with this approach. It's also likely to cause issues with any static analysis/linting tools.

Comment: I do not know about performance but for sure readability is affected. I will not use this in own my code because i will confuse myself at some point in future, only trying to help out.

Comment: Absolutely, it wasn't a criticism of your answer as I know you're trying to help the OP. I just want to be clear on this question that the overcomplication that the OP is aiming for is not good practice.